# Karatsuba's p-adic analogue of Vinogradov's method.

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

One can use an argument based on work by Vinogradov to show that the Riemann zeta function has a zero-free region very close to the line $\text{Re }s = 1$. Titchmarsh describes this approach in chapter 6 of his book on the zeta function and also notes that Karatsuba presents a greatly simplified argument using $p$-adic methods.

This latter material can be found in Karatsuba's book on analytic number theory, but I do not have access to that volume. Is there a source online which describes this approach?

Comment: Did you study 3.10 and 3.9 ([p.64](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Titchmarsh-The_theory_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function.pdf)) ? He explains how from a bound for $\zeta(\sigma+it)$ we can deduce a zero-free region, using the properties of $\zeta$